# how to get content even if we have error code response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I create HTTP GET like this:

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
```

Work great! But Imagine that server return error 201 or error 206. How to get content of response even error code is not 200? I do not want to use another library, I want to do this using HttpURLConnection

Comment: not sure exactly what you want, any error would just be in your response, you'd have to examine it and determine what to do and that depends entirely on what your program is doing. a web browser would display it to screen for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedReader rd = null;

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        } else {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getErrorStream()));
        }

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
```